# vb.net Mock an "iterative database" connection inside the managed code

Tags: vb.net, loops, unit-testing

Problem: I am refactoring vb.net code to make it more unit test friendly. I have a vb.net function which has 2 data components. In the original code, both data models were implemented in the code which made it almost impossible to pass test data. I implemented an interface for the first data object which is now injected into the call to the function. This solves the issue of passing mock data to the function when testing. The second data component is executed iteratively inside the function.

Question - Is there a way to "mock" the iterative data retrieval while still maintaining the code functionality?

Basic Function - The data object injected at call time is used to pass parameters to the second database call within the code. This is repeated for each row in the injected DataTable object.

Function Signature: date and dailyScores are injected for Unit Tests or Run Time Execution

```vb
Public Shared Function CalcDailyScoresByDate(ByVal dayUtc As Date,
                                             ByVal ReID As Integer,
                                             ByVal dailyScores As DataTable
                                             ) As DailyDataCollection
```

Function Code:

```
Public Shared Function CalcDailyScoresByDate(ByVal dayUtc As Date,
                                             ByVal ReID As Integer,
                                             ByVal dailyScores As DataTable
                                             ) As DailyDataCollection
    Dim timeUtc As Date = dayUtc 
    Dim srvSet As ServiceSettings = New ServiceSettings(dayUtc)
    Dim ept As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, TimeZoneInfo.Local)
    ept = ept.AddDays(1)
    Dim effDayUtc As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(ept)
    Dim daily As New DailyDataCollection
        
    Try

        #Region "Region DataAccess"

        Dim regDs = New DataAccess
        
        Try
            regDs.InitializeFromMDB(srvSet.MyConnectionString, "MyDb")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MyUtil.ErrorLog("RegDS.InitializeFromMDB " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        
        For Each rw In dailyScores.Rows
            Dim drw As New DailyData

            drw.ReID = rw(0)
            drw.SignalID = rw(1) 
            drw.MyDay = effDayUtc
            drw.dailyScore = rw(2) 
        
            ' Calls the actual implementation to retrieve the supporting data for each record in the outer for loop
            ' Need to find a way to allow this to be Unit Tested with Mock data
            Dim rsc = regDs.GetRegResource(drw.ReID, drw.SignalID, effDayUtc)  
        
            If rsc.Type = DataAccess.ReTypes.DG Then                              
                For Each child In rsc.Children                                                
                    Dim childDaily As New DailyData
                    childDaily.ReID = child.ID
                    childDaily.SignalID = child.SignalID
                    childDaily.myDay = effDayUtc
                    childDaily.dailyScore = drw.dailyScore
                    daily.Add(childDaily)                                                      
                Next
            End If
                            
        Next
        dailyScores.Dispose()
        dailyScores = Nothing
        srvSet = Nothing
        
        #End Region
            
    Catch ex As Exception
        MyUtil.ErrorLog("CalcDailyScoresByDate: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
            
    Return daily
End Function
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading about dependency injection.  You have several `New` declarations in your function that are creating hard-coded dependencies.  You should think about how you might refactor the routine to take these as arguments.  Most likely, they should turn into some sort of interface so you can provide a different test implementation, but depending on how they get used, they might even turn into some sort of delegate (maybe a named `Delegate` type, maybe a `Func` or an `Action`).

Comment: One option is to factor out your data access using the repository pattern. You can then mock the repository